# angular js function call with href while routing is configured

Tags: angularjs

Function is properly invoking when it calls with ng-click. But for my requirement of invoking that function for routing change(URL) I've made it with 'href' but its not working. guide on this. Syntax as follows;

```js
<!--VIEW-->

This call to controller was successfully
  < a class = "file"
data - ng - click = "vm.getDevices(true,'byLocation')" > Link One < /a>

If this URL captured, initialization function in the controller will be called indirectly
<a class="file" href="#/country/india/city/chennai ">Link Two</a>


//controller
(function () {
    'use strict';
  var controllerId = 'testController';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller(controllerId, ['$q', '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams']);

    function EsdEntryController($q, $scope, $location, $routeParams) {
 init();
 
 var vm = this
            , security = common.security
            , sortOrder;
   
    //page init functionality
    function init() {
  //route configured as below
  //url: '/country/:country/city/:city/'
  //
  if($routeParams.country=='india' && $routeParams.city=='chennai'){
   //calls to our function
   testFunction(param1, param2);//this call is not invoking properly 
  }
 }
      
 vm.testFunction = function (param1, param2) {
            getDevices(val1, val2');
        }

 function testFunction(param1, param2) {
   //function implementation here
  }
)();
```

Comment: You want some function called in routes change ?

Answer (score 0):

$routeParams requires you to inject ngRoute service.

Instead of

```
 angular.module('app')
```

Write this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```